# DataStream api using readFile only reads one file from the folder in batch mode

Tags: apache-flink

Writing a simple batch mode job, where i specify folder path. However only one file gets read in local mode, and when deployed to cluster the number of files read is the same as parallelism set. Simple code used for reading:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH)

    val trans_data: DataStream[MyClass] = env.readFile(
                                              RowCsvInputFormat.builder(
                                                MyClass.getRowTypeInformation(),
                                                new Path(salesPath)
                                              ).build(),
                                              salesPath
                                            ).map(x=>MyClass.convertFromRow(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StreamExecutionEnvironment#readFile` doesn't support the new unified batch/streaming source interface. You should probably use the new [FileSource](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/src/FileSource.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks! Still figuring stuff out, is there a better way to load CSV files, instead of reading as String and then mapping?

`val source = FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(new TextLineFormat(), new Path(path)).build()
val input: DataStream[MyClass] = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "my_source")
                                            .map(x => MyClass.convertFromString(x))`